# NHibernate 3.2 and Paging Oracle

Tags: oracle, nhibernate, pagination, version

I'm migrating web project asp.net VS2008 to VS2010, and NH 2.1 to NH 3.2.

Now, paging using NH 3.2 not work.

NHibernate 3.2 SetFirstresult, Setmaxresults paging problem oracle
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/nhusers/1kp0hDfVol0

Code, the same for vs2008 and vs2010, but using NH 3.2, paging not works

```
  var response = new GetComunicacionesXFiltroResponse();

        //Sesion
        using (ISession session = NHibernateHelper.OpenSession(FlushMode.Never))
        {
            IQuery query = GetQueryForGetComunicacionesXFiltro(request, false, session);
            if (request.PagingInfo != null)
            {
                query.SetMaxResults(request.PagingInfo.RowCount);
                query.SetFirstResult((request.PagingInfo.PageNumber - 1) * request.PagingInfo.RowCount);
            }
            response.Comunicaciones = ComunicacionMapper.Map(query.List<Comunicacion>());

        }
```

Config for NH 3.2

```
<hibernate-configuration  xmlns="urn:nhibernate-configuration-2.2" >
  <reflection-optimizer use="false"/>
  <session-factory>
    <property name="connection.connection_string_name">XXX.ConnectionStrings.Oracle.XXX</property>
    <property name="connection.provider">NHibernate.Connection.DriverConnectionProvider</property>
    <property name="connection.driver_class">NHibernate.Driver.OracleDataClientDriver</property>
    <property name="connection.isolation">ReadCommitted</property>
    <property name="dialect">NHibernate.Dialect.Oracle9iDialect</property>

    <property name="query.substitutions">true 1, false 0, yes 'Y', no 'N'</property>
    <property name="show_sql">false</property>
    <property name="use_proxy_validator">false</property>
    <!--DEPRECATED<property name="use_outer_join">true</property>-->
    <mapping assembly="XXX.MonitorizacionB2b.DomainModel"/>
  </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

any suggestions about it ?

Answer (score 0):

Iran into the same problem.  Paging is working in 3.3.  Download the source and compile it yourself or pull the nightly builds from

http://teamcity.codebetter.com/viewType.html?buildTypeId=bt7&tab=buildTypeStatusDiv

Comment: NH 3.3 is full stable - more than NH 3.2 ??

Comment: NH 3.3 was released 4/21/2012.