# Oracle 10g paging returns wrong resultset with 'rownum' and NHibernate

Tags: oracle, nhibernate, paging

Currently I encountered some strange behaviour in our application when paging data using Oracle 10g and NHibernate.

I have a table with 20 rows and I want to show 10 rows per site in a list, so my list has 2 pages.

Using NHibernate i'm setting for the first page `query.SetMaxResults(10).SetFirstResult(0)`,
and for the second page `query.SetMaxResults(10).SetFirstResult(10)`.

Following SQL will be created for first page:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE rownum <= 10;
```

Following SQL will be created for second page:

```
SELECT row_.*, rownum rownum_ 
FROM 
(
    SELECT * 
    FROM table
 ) row_ 
 WHERE rownum <= 20 WHERE rownum_ > 10;
```

First query returns the first 10 rows correctly, while the second query returns only 4 new rows and 6 rows that are already in "page 1". So 6 rows are completely missing.

So, I think, What the heck?

Comment: Can you post the full query? Are you eager loading any children?

Comment: Your second query is using the `rownum` from the outer query twice. You're not using the inner query at all.

Comment: your query looks mangled as you have two "WHERE" keywords on the outer query. was any DML going on between the time the 1 page was rendered and the 2nd? also theres no order by..so no guarantee of row order.

Answer (score 2):

You can create your own custom Oracle dialect to fix this issue, or you can wait for patch NH-3814 to be accepted. It would be best to wait for NHibernate to accept the patch, but if you do not have the time, you can do this.

https://nhibernate.jira.com/browse/NH-3814

This class will override a method from Oracle8iDialect to allow the rownum_ field to be used for both skip and take values.  I had to use reflection to call ExtractColumnOrAliasNames as that was a private method.

```
internal class Oracle10gDialectExtended : NHibernate.Dialect.Oracle10gDialect
{

    public Oracle10gDialectExtended()
    {
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// This is from patch NH-3814
    /// https://nhibernate.jira.com/browse/NH-3814
    /// https://nhibernate.jira.com/secure/attachment/24661/Oracle8iDialect.cs
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="sql"></param>
    /// <param name="offset"></param>
    /// <param name="limit"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public override NHibernate.SqlCommand.SqlString GetLimitString(NHibernate.SqlCommand.SqlString sql, NHibernate.SqlCommand.SqlString offset, NHibernate.SqlCommand.SqlString limit)
    {
        sql = sql.Trim();
        bool isForUpdate = false;
        if (sql.EndsWithCaseInsensitive(" for update"))
        {
            sql = sql.Substring(0, sql.Length - 11);
            isForUpdate = true;
        }

        string selectColumns = ExtractColumnOrAliasNames(sql);

        var pagingSelect = new SqlStringBuilder(sql.Count + 10);
        if (offset != null)
        {
            pagingSelect.Add("select " + selectColumns + " from ( select row_.*, rownum rownum_ from ( ");
        }
        else
        {
            pagingSelect.Add("select " + selectColumns + " from ( ");
        }

        pagingSelect.Add(sql);

        if (offset != null && limit != null)
        {
            pagingSelect.Add(" ) row_ ) where rownum_ <=").Add(limit).Add(" and rownum_ >").Add(offset);
        }
        else if (limit != null)
        {
            pagingSelect.Add(" ) where rownum <=").Add(limit);
        }
        else
        {
            // offset is specified, but limit is not.
            pagingSelect.Add(" ) row_ ) where rownum_ >").Add(offset);
        }

        if (isForUpdate)
        {
            pagingSelect.Add(" for update");
        }

        return pagingSelect.ToSqlString();
    }

    private string ExtractColumnOrAliasNames(SqlString select)
    {
        BindingFlags flags = BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Public;
        MethodInfo info = typeof(NHibernate.Dialect.Oracle8iDialect).GetMethod("ExtractColumnOrAliasNames", flags, null, new Type[] { typeof(SqlString) }, null);

        if (info == null)
        {
            throw new MissingMethodException("Method ExtractColumnOrAliasNames does not exist on class NHibernate.Dialect.Oracle8iDialect");
        }

        return info.Invoke(this, new object[] { select }) as string;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I am missing something, but I think you want this for your second query:

```
SELECT row_.*
FROM 
(
    SELECT *, rownum rn   --- place your rownum here
    FROM table
 ) row_ 
 WHERE rn > 10 
    and rn <=20
```

This applies the `rownum` to the inner query and then you select the records with a row number 11-20 in the `WHERE` clause.

Note, you should include an `ORDER BY` clause on both of your queries to be sure that the records are in the correct order when being returned.

Answer (score 0):

NH 3.2 has a problem with pagination on Oracle (similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10139766/nhibernate-3-2-and-paging-oracle)). I had the same problem and kept using 3.1 until it was fixed.

Answer (score -1):

I think Powerslave fat-fingered his example which originally included an *order by* and was something like:

```
SELECT * FROM 
    (SELECT row_.*, rownum rownum_ FROM 
        (
            SELECT * 
            FROM table
            ORDER BY some_column
        ) row_ 
        WHERE rownum <= 20) 
    WHERE rownum_ > 10;
```

Basically what's going on is NHibernate generates a query that:

1. Orders the results
2. Limits these to the first 20 ordered rows
3. Forgets about the ordering...
4. ...then takes *unordered* results 11-20.

The end result is you'll see the correct number of rows for every page, but some pages have row(s) that appear on other pages and there will be missing rows as well. I've run the NHibernate (4.0.3) generated queries by hand against Oracle to verify all of this to be true.

I've submitted both a bug report and patch to NHibernate [here](https://nhibernate.jira.com/browse/NH-3814). Hopefully my patch is kosher and they'll get this fixed in the next release.